# How to define `newState` in ReSwift with multiple sub-selects?

Tags: ios, swift, redux, reswift

We've used [ReSwift](https://github.com/ReSwift/ReSwift) in a few iOS projects and have been loving it. In [4.0](https://github.com/ReSwift/ReSwift/releases/tag/4.0.0), they added the ability to sub-select portions of the state and `skipRepeats`, either manually or using a store that's Equatable. Subselecting a store is straightforward:

```
store.subscribe(subscriber) {
  $0.select {
    $0.testValue
  }
}
```

Then you define `newState` with:

```
func newState(state:TestValue) {
   // handle new state
}
```

I'm a little stuck on how to define `newState` when passing multiple parameters via a tuple:

```
store.subscribe(subscriber) {
  $0.select {
    ($0.testValue, $0.otherState?.name)
  }
}
```

I'm passing the tuple but seeing the `Type 'MainViewController' does not conform to protocol 'StoreSubscriber'` and `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` errors:

```
func newState((testState: TestValue, name: String)) {
    // handle new state
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 4):

Of course it was a simple mistake on my part. I needed to name the tuple that I was passing, in this example as `state`

```
func newState(state: (testState: TestValue, name: String)) {
    // handle new state
}
```

Comment: I was seeing the same thing! Nice catch mate :+1: